# How to overriding model in django third party app?

Tags: django

I want to modified django third party model. Here the original code.

```
default_price = models.DecimalField(
        decimal_places=2, max_digits=7,
        null=True, blank=True,
        verbose_name=_("Default price"),
    )
```

I want to change `max_digits=7` to `max_digits=9`, so it becomes:

```
default_price = models.DecimalField(
        decimal_places=2, max_digits=9,
        null=True, blank=True,
        verbose_name=_("Default price"),
    )
```

Is it possible to modified django third party model without directly touch original third party code or fork?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550434/how-to-override-a-django-reusable-apps-model#answer-12551558

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it with this two lines code in my models:

```
from thirdparty.models import ParentModelClass
ParentModelClass._meta.get_field('default_price').max_digits = 9
```

then makemigrations && migrate

voila it work, but i don't know any downside using this tricks.

It thanks to Peterino comments on this https://stackoverflow.com/a/2357942/2579404

Hope it will help others with similar situation as well.